# Kähler metric on projectivised bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a holomorphic bundle over a Kähler manifold. Does its projectivisation $\mathbb{P}(E)$ always admit a Kähler metric? If yes, how to see that?

Comment: You can find the answer for more detail with proof here  Lemma 4.2.3 https://dipot.ulb.ac.be/dspace/bitstream/2013/209324/1/bec8d467-b463-4b7e-955c-0fa0bd312e03.txt . See Lemma 1  of this paper also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2198.pdf

Answer (score 9):

Let me recall you briefly how to obtain such a Kähler metric on the total space of the projectivized bundle.

Start with any given hermitian metric $h$ on $E$ and consider on the projectivized bundle $\mathbb P(E)$ of hyperplanes of $E$ the tautological line bundle $\mathcal O_E(1)\to\mathbb P(E)$ of rank one quotients of $E$. Then, on $\mathcal O_E(1)$ you have a natural induced quotient hermitian metric, which I shall call again $h$.

If you compute the Chern curvature $\Theta(\mathcal O_E(1))$ of $\mathcal O_E(1)$ with respect to $h$, you will find a closed $(1,1)$-form on $\mathbb P(E)$ which is positive along the relative tangent bundle (after all, the restricion of $\mathcal O_E(1)$ to fibers $\simeq\mathbb P^{\operatorname{rk}E-1}$is just the usual $\mathcal O(1)$, so that its curvature restricted to fibers is just the usual Fubini-Study metric). No more can be said along "horizontal" directions.

Now, suppose that $M$ is compact Kähler, with Kähler form $\omega$ and call $\pi\colon\mathbb P(E)\to M$ the natural projection. Since $E$ is holomorphic (see Francesco's answer), $\pi$ is holomorphic as well. Thus, $\pi^*\omega$ is again a closed $(1,1)$-form on $\mathbb P(E)$ which is zero on vertical directions (as a pull-back) and strictly positive on horizontal ones.

Finally, by compactness of $M$, and so of $\mathbb P(E)$, you can find a large constant $C$ such that the closed $(1,1)$-form
$$
C\,\pi^*\omega+i\,\Theta(\mathcal O_E(1))
$$
is positive definite everywhere (such a large multiple is chosen in such a way that $\omega$ compensates the possible lack of positivity of $\Theta(\mathcal O_E(1))$ along horizontal directions, and observe that $\omega$ does not interfere with the vertical ones).

This gives you the desired Kähler metric on $\mathbb P(E)$.

Comment: You can find your answer for more detail with proof here  Lemma 4.2.3 https://dipot.ulb.ac.be/dspace/bitstream/2013/209324/1/bec8d467-b463-4b7e-955c-0fa0bd312e03.txt . See Lemma 1  of this paper also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.2198.pdf

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Georges Elencwajg, the answer is **yes**.

However, if one substitutes the assumption "holomorphic vector bundle" with the weaker "complex vector bundle", the answer is **no**.

In fact, there is the following result proven by C. Voisin.

Start with a complex Kähler manifold $X$ having a given class $\alpha \in H^4(X, \mathbb{Q})$ such that, for any given compatible Hodge decomposition on $H^*(X)$, $\alpha$ is not of type $(2,2)$.

Then if $E$ is any complex vector bundle on $X$ satisfying $$c_1(E)=0, \quad c_2(E)=\alpha,$$ the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E)$ admits no Kähler metric (even better, it is not homeomorhic to any Kähler manifold).

The simplest example of such a pair $(X, \alpha)$ is obtained by choosing for $X$ a complex
torus of dimension $4$ and for $\alpha$ a class satisfying the property that the cup product map $$\alpha \cup \colon H^1(X, \mathbb{Q}) \longrightarrow H^5(X, \mathbb{Q})$$
has odd rank.

See [these notes](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~voisin/Articlesweb/verbanianotes.pdf) by C. Voisin for more details.

Answer (score 6):

If $M$ is compact ( the usual assumption  in Kähler manifold theory)  the answer is "yes". You can look it up in Claire Voisin's [book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Hodge_Theory_and_Complex_Algebraic_Geome.html?id=AhSqPwAACAAJ) Proposition 3.18, page 78.

Comment: Quite amusing: Francesco posted his counter-example while I was writing up my positive answer! I can only hope for Voisin's sake that the  $X$ mentioned in Francesco's post is not compact...

Comment: Dear Geoges, your answer is correct. I think the point is that in Voisin's examples the vector bundle $E$ is *complex* but not *holomorphic* 

Comment: Dear Francesco, thanks for the quick clarification.