# Kahlerness of the projectivized cotangent bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth not necessarily compact complex manifold which admits a Kahler metric. **Is it true that its projectivized cotangent bundle also admits a Kahler metric?** If not, are there sufficient conditions for that?

Comment: This seems like a fairly specific question. Is there some motivation for this?

Comment: Call your space $P$. It has a projection $\pi:P\to X$. It's a projective space bundle. So $P$ has a positive semidefinite $(1,1)$-form $\phi$ which restricts to the Fubini-Study form on the fibres (I'll let you check). Now consider $\phi+\pi^*\omega$, where $\omega$ is the Kahler form on $X$...

Comment: @DonuArapura: Do I understand correctly that the projectivization of ANY holomorphic vector bundle over a Kahler manifold is Kahler?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I am not an algebraic geometer. I am interested in convergence properties of projectivized conormal bundles $N(M_i)$ of a sequence of a smooth compact submanifolds $\{M_i\}$. The convergence is understood in the sense of currents. To apply the Federer-Fleming compactness theorem, I have to find a uniform upper bound on volumes of $N(M_i)$ no matter with respect to which Riemannian metric.

Comment: It is convenient to use a Kahler metric since then it would be sufficient to show that all $N(M_i)$ represent the same homology class which is easily satisfied in my case.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68843/k%C3%A4hler-metric-on-projectivised-bundle