# Kähler metric on projective bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a holomorphic bundle over a compact Kähler manifold, then as discussed in [Kähler metric on projectivised bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68843/k%c3%a4hler-metric-on-projectivised-bundle), $\mathbb P(E)$ admits Kähler metric. If we just consider a projective bundle over a compact Kähler manifold (may not be the projection of an vector bundle), can we have the same conclusion?

Comment: Yes.  The pushforward of the dual of the relative canonical (invertible) sheaf is a holomorphic vector bundle on the base Kaehler manifold.  The projectivization is a Kaehler manifold.  There is a closed holomorphic embedding of the total space of the original bundle in this new Kaehler manifold.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean precisely (i.e. what category this bundle with fibres equal to projective space is in). For example if it is just a topological bundle then there are $\mathbb{CP}^1$-bundles over $T^2$ which are not orientable. I am guess Jason Starr's answer assumes that the bundle is a complex manifold and the bundle map is holomorphic .

Comment: @NickL  Yes, indeed!  I did interpret the OP's question to mean the case when the total space is a complex manifold and the projection to the base is a holomorphic submersion that (analytically locally on the base) is just a product of the base and a fixed projective space.

Comment: @JasonStarr, thanks, your answer seems promising. But I am not an expert in algebraic geometry and I don't understand your construction well. Could you explain a little about what is the relative canonical sheaf and why there is a closed holomorphic embedding as you mentioned?